# Unique complements in a distributive lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

I know that

> In a distributive lattce L, a given element can have at most one complement.

But are following points correct:

- In complimented distributive lattices, complements are unique.
- If compliments are unique in a lattice then it must be a distributive lattice.

Comment: *Complemented* is the word you want, unless the elements of the lattice are very very polite.

Answer (score 3):

Your bullet point 1 is correct, and it follows from your statement:

> In a distributive lattice $L$, a given element can have at most one complement.

[If $L$ is a complemented lattice, each element has at least one complement. As you note, in the distributive case it has at most one complement. Together these mean the lattice is uniquely complemented.]

Your bullet point 2 is not correct. It is a famous result of Dilworth that every lattice is embeddable in a uniquely complemented lattice. See

R.P. Dilworth, Lattices with unique complements, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 57 (1945), 123-154.

Comment: yeah I know first point is kinda stupid, it was direct implication of the quoted fact. In fact I came across following (confusing/possibly wrong) statement in one of the sources: a "complemented" lattice is distributive iff every element has a unique complement. Its not even like that right?. (Noob in lattice theory... :\)

Comment: The "Fact" you quote is false in general, but it is true for finite lattices.